# How can I add my telemetry server to nearcore config.json?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I want to read telemetry data from `nearcore` and I know the node is compatible with Prometheus. The file `config.json` contains the voice telemetry, which points to NEAR block explorer:

```
 "telemetry": {
    "endpoints": [
      "https://explorer.betanet.nearprotocol.com/api/nodes"
    ]
  },
```

Can I add my own telemetry server to that array? Which port should I open on the firewall?

Comment: Our telemetry is not related to prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to host a near explorer: https://github.com/near/near-explorer and use its url as telemetry server. Telemetry request is outbound traffic from neard (request is from neard to the explorer), so you don't need to open any port for neard node.

Comment: Is there a way to use an existing Prometheus server, and collect the data without running any explorer?

Comment: No, prometheus data is different from explorer data:
- prometheus data is exported via node_ip:3030/metrics, you can configure your prometheus server to collect metrics from this url.
- telemetry url is exclusively for near-explorer and have to be received by a near-explorer backend

Comment: Thank you, this is the reply I was looking for. I don't need an explorer but a way to monitor the node status.
Will point my Prometheus/Grafana to `<node_ip>:3030/metrics`